# Mockserver is crushing when running on minikube docker M1

Tags: java, apple-m1, minikube, mockserver

I am running minikube on my M1 machine i.e. arm64 arch
The minikunbe start command is:

```
minikube start -p foobar --kubernetes-version=v1.23.16 --container-runtime=docker --vm=true --network socker_vmnet --cpus 4 --memory 10g
```

When pulling mockserver image i.e.

```
docker pull mockserver/mockserver:5.15.0
```

You can see that the result of the `pull` command and specifically the architecture which is arm64:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:95de41c9a8f374c82ed7ddb5c3c239d745667a6c6ef37819d48507e8039aab68",
        "RepoTags": [
            "mockserver/mockserver:5.15.0"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "mockserver/mockserver@sha256:0f9ef78c94894ac3e70135d156193b25e23872575d58e2228344964273b4af6b"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
        "Created": "2023-01-12T09:24:32.534016275Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "",
        "Author": "James Bloom \"jamesdbloom@gmail.com\"",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "nonroot",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "1080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "JAVA_VERSION=17.0.4",
                "LANG=C.UTF-8",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
                "SERVER_PORT=1080"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/home/nonroot",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "java",
                "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
                "-cp",
                "/mockserver-netty-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/libs/*",
                "-Dmockserver.propertyFile=/config/mockserver.properties",
                "org.mockserver.cli.Main"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "arm64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 275668416,
        "VirtualSize": 275668416,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/09023f315a1db5df781df9dcd495575e3fa5ffc869b05867b9dbdac6cc0f43d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c12958ff74a0d0b38d4a9078418a133896971503074d220a2b55a96ff1890cf1/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ba271473e4a6fb358e7626e548de976505a9c637a67b5d3e1f3590c3bdc779af/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c07b166a9ffcc1ee4c0d6f46887384750e467ea8c47cde14b84295b43afd77ec/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/443d2ed633d45c7be4c7d317cf9d4c138a80ba3e15fc4ed6427679efc4f2c70d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/581bd89c864cd38bd32c9a42f115f4921c427804b91e870ed3e561c905557638/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1b978f0a0fd1f88dc3afb29152ffec3be06243dde3063f5bb3e51b11c4551881/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1b978f0a0fd1f88dc3afb29152ffec3be06243dde3063f5bb3e51b11c4551881/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1b978f0a0fd1f88dc3afb29152ffec3be06243dde3063f5bb3e51b11c4551881/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:cb60fb9b862c6a89f92e484bc3b72bbc0352b41166df5c4a68bfb52f52504a7d",
                "sha256:00c562532b203116c721c11aee6fe1fe50b5e2068cee2c343c1df1050a866b3e",
                "sha256:e83d4114481dc897d49d5a9a8b68bf71c4f08f1a5c1adff44603c56b958fed53",
                "sha256:45f84957a62ddbeee272fc25653d35160f934dd8bb930bc0d30b80d1cfb7cfd3",
                "sha256:468a6b28e336b9ead462b8128b8d8c60e458a1facc41b5e925fca21b6718c368",
                "sha256:f753c3e5f9d750c2e2b830fcb428451aa734456474d25fba225041ed34c29f05",
                "sha256:bccdbe648bac42eb712b7623e7134b1ff1cb0be076d19174482e80d71f664949"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

when running : `docker run -d --rm --platform linux/arm64 -P mockserver/mockserver:5.15.0`. I am getting the same java error expected from the incompatibility of amd64 images running on arm64 machines i.e.

```
exec /usr/bin/java: exec format error
```

I am not sure what the issue is and I can't find anything wrong with the image and arch type.

Can you?